# Proper way to serialize json in database with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Let's say that I have this kind of json.

In rails, I have three models:

*Section* that have many *Questions*

And *Questions* have one *Answer*

What is the proper way to save/update it in database ?

Thanks in advance for any help

```
{
"id": 1,
"section_name_fr": "Section1",
"section_number": 1,
"questions": [
{
    "id": 2,
    "question_fr": "Question12FR",
    "input_type": "textarea",
    "answer": {
        "id": 1,
        "answer": "Blabla"
    }
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "question_fr": "Question14FR",
    "input_type": "tel",
    "answer": null
}
]
}
```

Comment: The PostgreSQL has native support for json and quite good support for stored procedures. You want to solve it on ruby-on-rails side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your example json is in a variable `json`. Then we can:

```
section_attributes = JSON.parse(json).symbolize_keys
# update section
section = Section.find_or_create_by id: section_attributes[:id]
section.update_attributes! section_attributes.slice(:section_name_fr, :section_number)
section_attributes[:questions].each do |question_attributes|
  # update question
  question = section.questions.find_or_create_by id: question_attributes[:id]
  question.update_attributes! question_attributes.slice(:question_fr, :input_type)
  # update answer
  (question.answer || question.build_answer).update_attributes question_attributes[:answer].slice(:answer)
end
```

Note that this makes some assumptions about how you want the saving/updating to behave. For example, with questions, we try to find a question already in the given section with the given ID. If we can't find it, we create one. However, you may wish to search for *any* question with the given ID and associate with the section. In that case you would replace the update question lines with:

```
question = Question.find_or_create_by id: question_attributes[:id]
question.update_attributes! question_attributes.slice(:question_fr, :input_type).merge(section_id: section.id)
```

Also note that the use of `slice` on the attribute hashes is important for security reasons. In particular, it defines which attributes the json is allowed to modify.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to cast your json at hash ruby format:

```
json ='{
"id": 1,
"section_name_fr": "Section1",
"section_number": 1,
"questions": [
             {
              "id": 2,
              "question_fr": "Question12FR",
              "input_type": "textarea",
              "answer": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "answer": "Blabla"
                        }
             },
              {
               "id": 4,
               "question_fr": "Question14FR",
               "input_type": "tel",
               "answer": null
              }
 ]
 }'
```

`hash_ruby = JSON.parse(json)`

Then

```
section = Section.find_or_create(id:hash_ruby["id"])
section.name_fr = hash_ruby["section_name_fr"]
section.number = hash_ruby["section_number"]
section.save
hash_ruby["questions"].each do |q|
  new_question = Question.find_or_create(id:q["id"])
  new_question.question_fr = q["question_fr"]
  new_question.input_type = q["input_type"]
  if !(q["answer"].nil?)
    answer = Answer.find_or_create(id:q["anwser"]["id"])
    answer.anwser = q["anwser"]["anwser"]
    answer.save
    new_question.answer=answer
  end
  new_question.section = section
  new_question.save
end
```

I had suppose that the model Question contain a section foreign key and Question contain a anwser foreign key